# Synchronization with Oracle

Tags: oracle, synchronization

I have an old version of Oracle installed in my WINDOWS XP virtual machine. I want to synchronize this database with an oracle database installed on my local machine. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronize"? What versions of Oracle are we talking about? Is there network connectivity between the two machines? What have you already tried? And what exactly does this have to do with code development? This might be better asked at https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I think you want to export the data to a new oracle?  read up on exp and imp or expdp impdp

Comment: @OldProgrammer you can say that, but exporting won't make the results synchronized !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to synchronize two Oracle databases, then you need to configure physical standby between two databases. Any change in the primary database will be instantly applied to the secondary using a redo log.
To configure standby first, you need to replicate the complete database.

You can check the steps of doing it for oracle 12c here:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/data-guard-setup-using-broker-12cr1

You will find your version-appropriate steps by searching data guard or physical standby database in google. Thanks.